# My newly built tower is not recognizing the fact that there is a video card in it

Tags: graphics-card, bios, computer-building

The onboard video works so that i can explore the problem, but so far, i can't find the video card in the device manager, and i don't have any options for the PCI-E or the GPU, in the BIOS unless im missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Pick one of these:

- You didn't insert the card correctly.
- You didn't attach all required power cords to the card.
- Your card is defective.
- Your mainboard is defective.

Comment: everything is brand new. the computer is on and working so that can't be defective, as for the cable that attaches to the video card, i have a 6 pin, 2 pin connector attached but the video card is only 6 pins so the 2pin is just hanging there

Comment: @an1m473dph33r Does your GPU run ? you know the fans

Comment: yes the fans are on

Comment: i just finally was able to get the driver disk to open and install the drivers,but when the tower came back on it, said cannot find ASUS graphics card

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: should i disable the onboard video card?

Comment: You might need to select the card in the BIOS. Many onboard graphics cards use the same PCIe lanes as the expansion slot, so both cards cannot operate at the same time.

Comment: PCIe is the main option for graphics in the BIOS

Answer (score 0):

Some mainboards (with integrate graphic) have option to enable or disable graphic card in BIOS. Have you try looking into it?  Or maybe you have to disable the onboard graphic for external graphic to works.

Comment: none of these suggestions has helped. My video card still isn't working. I'm pretty sure the power is hooked up correctly, the fan is blowing when the computer is on, but it still is not telling me ytheres any other GPU device besides the onboard video.